# Javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to make a simple function with js & jquery but I can't get this to work.

From what I understand, when I declare a variable without var it becomes global but I can pass a variable from a jquery callback to my main function.

```
   function fetchEvents(start,end){
        ret = [];
        $j.getJSON("index.php?page=agenda_google_ajax&action=list&start="+start+"&end="+end,function(data){
            console.log(data); // works ok
            ret = data;
        });
        console.log(ret); // equals [] :'(
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: you might want to read up on javascript async

Comment: Does ret variable needs to be an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand, when I declare a variable with var it becomes global..

The opposite is true. When you omit `var`, the variable becomes global. Always use var!

From the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml):

> When you fail to specify var, the
>   variable gets placed in the global
>   context, potentially clobbering
>   existing values. Also, if there's no
>   declaration, it's hard to tell in what
>   scope a variable lives (e.g., it could
>   be in the Document or Window just as
>   easily as in the local scope). So
>   always declare with var.

As for your problem with `console.log(ret); // equals [] :'(`...

`$j.getJSON()` is not a synchronous method call. The method runs asynchronously, so your code effectively says:

```
ret = [];
console.log(ret);
```

If you need to use the data returned from your getJSON() after it is executed, you can call a method within your callback function:

```
$j.getJSON("index.php?page=agenda_google_ajax&action=list&start="+start+"&end="+end,
    function(data){      // this is your callback function
      console.log(data); // works ok
      doSomething(data); // process the returned JSON
    }
});
```

Comment: @Paté create a global function call `test()` and within that function call `console.log(ret)` now in your getJSON callback function call `test()` and see what you get

Comment: @Paté - I added a code example to demonstrate how you might want to use the returned data.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that $.getJSON uses a callback so when your fetchEvents function is called it returns before the callback is executed.

what you want to do is in the callback populate/do the stuff you want to do.

as you have pointed out console.log works ok in the callback

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are confusing 2 issues here.

The first is that `var` does not make a variable gloabl.  The opposite is true.  That is omitting `var` will make a variable global.

The second is the `getJSON` callback method does not execute synchronously.  It will execute once the http request is completed.  So there is no expectation that `ret` will be set to the value immediately after making the `getJSON` call.

Answer (score 0):

try adding var to `var ret = [];`

Comment: @pate you need to make you request async: false

Comment: pate will have to use `.ajax` and not `.getJSON` to set `async: false`

Answer (score 0):

adding var to it does not make it global, omitting it makes it global it is added to the global window object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because ret is evaluated BEFORE you get a response from ajax. Try

```
function fetchEvents(start,end){
        $j.getJSON("index.php?page=agenda_google_ajax&action=list&start="+start+"&end="+end,function(data){
            console.log(data); // works ok
            var ret = data
            whatsRet (ret);
        });
        }

function whatsRet (ret) {
        console.log(ret); // equals data :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is about writing asynchronous code.

When you call `getJSON`, the inner function will not be called until `getJSON` returns something. This means that code is no longer executed top-down, your program continues the execution even when `getJSON` is still getting the data.

You should provide a `callback` instead of a `return`:

```
var fetchEvents = function (start, end, callback) {
  $j.getJSON("index.php?start="+start+"&end="+end, function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
};

// Now you can use fetchEvents which will be asynchronous too
fetchEvents(0, 10, function (data) {
  console.log(data);
})
```

You can simpify `fetchEvents` event more by passing the `callback` directly to `getJSON`.

```
var fetchEvents = function (start, end, callback) {
  $j.getJSON("index.php?start="+start+"&end="+end, callback);
};
```

PD: I simplified the query for readability.