# Undefined ctx variable

Tags: javascript

I have a script which keeps telling me ctx is undefined but yet a different variable is still set in the script which was made at the same place... so im confused why one variable is set and not the other.

The error is:
Uncaught ReferenceError: ctx is not defined on line 32 (i commented line 32)

Yet var canvas is defined =/

This is my script:

```
var tiles = Array("1.png","0.png"); 
var loaded = 0; 
var loadTimer; 


function loadimg(){
 var tileImg = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<tiles.length;i++){
    tileImg[i] = new Image();
    tileImg[i].src = tiles[i]; 
    tileImg[i].onload = function(){ 
        loaded++;
    }
  }
}

function loadall(){ 
if(loaded == tiles.length){
    clearInterval(loadTimer);
    loadTimer = setInterval(gameUpdate,100); 
 }
} 

function gameUpdate(){ 
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //line 32
draw();
}

function init(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
loadimg(); 
loadTimer = setInterval(loadall,100);
}
```

Hope you can help explain my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about scope, the variable will only exist in the block of code it is defined. Move your definitions to the top of the code.

```
var tiles = Array("1.png","0.png"); 
var loaded = 0; 
var loadTimer; 
var ctx;
var canvas;

function loadimg(){
 var tileImg = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<tiles.length;i++){
    tileImg[i] = new Image();
    tileImg[i].src = tiles[i]; 
    tileImg[i].onload = function(){ 
        loaded++;
    }
  }
}

function loadall(){ 
if(loaded == tiles.length){
    clearInterval(loadTimer);
    loadTimer = setInterval(gameUpdate,100); 
 }
} 

function gameUpdate(){ 
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //line 32
draw();
}

function init(){
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
loadimg(); 
loadTimer = setInterval(loadall,100);
}
```

Comment: Well i got my script from dissecting another script:
http://glacialflame.com/tutorials/tiles/02/

His script has the ctx in the init function and yet doesn't produce the same undefined error. So i am confused by this. Whats different about his ?

Comment: The script on that page doesn't include the **var** keyword. In Javascript, if you don't define a variable using **var**, it will be automatically declared as global (i.e. the same as placing it at the top of your code).

Answer (score 2):

As you define `ctx` within the init-function, `ctx` will be private to that function, thus not available at line 32. The execution stops at `ctx`, since it isn't available inside `gameupdate()`, therefore you don't get an error about `canvas` (yet!). If you make `ctx` available to all functions by declaring it outside the init-function, your error will move to the canvas-variable (since that is private to init-function as well), stating that `canvas` isn't declared.

To make the variables available to all functions, do the declaration at the top of your script, outside the function. Then remove the `var` keyword from you init-function and simply assign the variables instead:

```
var ctx, canvas;

// ... all your functions

function init(){
   canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
   loadimg(); 
   loadTimer = setInterval(loadall,100);
}
```

For more information on variable scoping in JavaScript, have a look at this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: Yeh but if you see the page source of the link i posted above in the comments of DJohnson's post that link has it inside the init function =/ but doesn't produce the same issue.

Comment: @Dave He omits the `var` keyword when he declare his variables, then the variable doesn't get private, it ends up in the global namespace instead, thus becomes available to all functions. This is often considered bad practice though as it pollutes the global namespace, and there is a risk that it might interfere with other scripts on the same page, using the same variable names. You can Google on namespacing in javascript, if you want to read up more about that.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess, but in order for this to work:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

You need to have a

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Element in your html.

Otherwise, `getElementById("canvas")` will not return a canvas and `canvas.getContext("2d");` will not set the ctx var.

**EDIT**: also see DJohnson's post regarding the scope of your canvas and ctx variables.

If you omit the var keyword, the scope of a variable will be global.
see: [Javascript variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474271/javascript-variable-scope)

In your sample, you have defined it locally using

```
function init(){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
```

That is why you cannot access it in another function (and that is also what is different from the reference you posted).

So this would work:

```
function init(){
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // not var keyword
}
```

And this would be proper:

```
var ctx;

function init(){
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
```

Comment: My canvas is on my html page:

    <body onLoad="init();"> 
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1200px" height="600px"     class="canvas">Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.</canvas>