# Simple Javascript program: Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am stuck on an exercise that asks to create a simple calculator. The user input is delegated to a separate function so that I may expand the program to subtraction, multiplication and division without repeating lines.

The error is:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lesson 6 Lab Exercise 3 - Calculator with user input</title>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                function getNumbers()
                {
                    var x = prompt("Enter the first number:");
                    var y = prompt("Enter the second number:");
                    x = parseInt(x);
                    y = parseInt(y);
                }

                function addition()
                {
                    getNumbers();   
                    document.write(x + "+" + y + "=" + (x+y));
                }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addition()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: x is only available within the getNumbers function body

Comment: You defined the variable x outside of the ```addition``` function. It gets created when you call ```getNumbers()```, and destroyed when the function exits. Look up variable scope in javascript, this might be a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Exactly the same problem as [Undefined ctx variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448850/undefined-ctx-variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other answers say, you should pass `x` and `y` from one function to another. I do not agree with the zmo's approach using array, so here is a short object option (main difference from karthikr's post is that it is shorter):

```
function getNumbers()
{
    var x = prompt("Enter the first number:");
    var y = prompt("Enter the second number:");
    x = parseInt(x);
    y = parseInt(y);
    return { x: x, y: y };
}

function addition()
{
    var numbers = getNumbers();   
    document.write(numbers.x + "+" + numbers.y + "=" + (numbers.x+numbers.y));
}
```

Some additional information as requested in comments:

1. `{ x: x, y: y }` is an object defined using literal object notation (or object initializer).
   See [Using object initializers (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers).
2. General form of that syntax is `{ property1: value1, property2: value2 /*, etc*/ }`. This basically defines a map that allows you to get `value1` using key `property1` (similar to hashtables/dictionaries in other languages).
   So `{ x: x }` defines an object where value of property `x` is equal to variable named `x`. This might be a bit confusing, but the property name and value are completely separate things and just happened to have the same name at this time.
3. After the object has been defined, you can access property values by using several different approaches. Most common are `object.property1` or `object['property1']`.
   See [Objects and properties (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

Btw if there is a better tutorial than MDN please let me know and I'll update the links.

Comment: err... basically karthikr and @HMR suggested using an object to return the values... and their post are only down the page. And in regard of returning an object, I do actually prefer HMR's solution.

Comment: karthikr's post is similar, but more verbose. HMR's post is a totally different approach (it does not return an object, it happens within an object).

Comment: @zmo I like mine/your approach much more than HMR's because HMR's introduces state, but the problem can be solved with stateless functions. stateless > stateful wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the outpouring of assistance. I accepted Andrey's answer as it is the simplest, and the only one I can remotely understand. @zmo I like your solution too but it is doesn't appear to work in chrome.

Comment: What are the terms for variables with a colon (x:x) and a dot (numbers.x) in between them? I am trying to google for more information.

Comment: @Brian Thanks, I have updated the answer with detailed description and links. Please let me know if something is unclear in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
                var x;
                var y;
                function getNumbers()
                {
                    x = prompt("Enter the first number:");
                    y = prompt("Enter the second number:");
                    x = parseInt(x);
                    y = parseInt(y);
                }

                function addition()
                {
                    getNumbers();   
                    document.write(x + "+" + y + "=" + (x+y));
                }
```

Define the variables outside of the function, so that they are in scope in both methods.
You can define the entire code block in a closure to avoid adding the variables to global space.

Comment: Just dumping variables in the global scope to solve scoping problems is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I don't get the pickiness.  The asker isn't designing a website for a client, they're playing with JavaScript and trying to learn.  Save scope concerns for later.

Comment: @DanielGimenez exactly, the OP is **learning** and thus shall learn what is a good design and what is not. And using *globals* is always a bad design, however easy it is to use them in JS.

Comment: I would argue that the key point here is to point out why the current code doesn't work. That lesson is just as important as learning proper patterns

Comment: @DanielGimenez `they're playing with JavaScript and trying to learn.` That's why it's best to educate early before bad habits are picked up.  I do use globals in many code examples on SO though but assume the people reading them know that in practice this would be wrapped in an object.

Comment: @TGH Valid point, but I do think it's best to fiddle with code knowing the right patterns first (OOP design). I usually advice people who want to learn programming to check out the Java tutorail first. This because it's a good step by step tutorial to get a grasp on class based OOP. Later they can learn about prototype (Ecma 6 will have classes and interfaces) and there are tons of tutorials out there for that. Spaghetti code might be ok to learn a language but if learning programming is the objective then maybe not a good idea.

Comment: Sure, but it's not necessarily the case that my solution is a bad pattern. If the code is wrapped in a closure - scope will be limited to the closure. It's IMO similar to private member fields in a class

Comment: @MHR, you have to learn to walk before you can run.  If you haven't grasped the concept of scope then its way too soon to be concerned with patterns and good OOP design.

Comment: @DanielGimenez scope is a fundamental knowledge, and managing one's objects lifes throughout the algorithm is the most basic yet important skill a programmer should have. So it's never too early to teach **globals are evil**, the same way most will agree **eval is evil**, or **goto is evil**.

Comment: I think the reason why it is not the best solution has nothing to do with globals being global. The reason why it is not the best solution is because it introduces mutable shared state where there is no need for shared state at all. Both functions can be implemented in a stateless way, which is a better pattern to learn as it decouples them and makes data flow and application state clear at each given moment.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin: The point I'm trying to make is that it doesn't have to be in the window scope unless you want it to be. It can be wrapped in a javascript closure. In fairness your argument against global scope must be applied to the methods as well since they too will be in global scope unless a closure is added :-).

Comment: @TGH My argument is not on scope: it is against shared _state_ (variables shared between functions in this case). You could wrap it in an inner scope and still it would be worse than making several independent functions with no shared state.

Answer (score 1):

Made some corrections to the code and added a check if both x and y are numbers.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lesson 6 Lab Exercise 3 - Calculator with user input</title>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
              var Calculator={
                x:0,
                y:0,
                getNumbers:function()
                {
                    // reset x and y
                    this.x=NaN;
                    this.y=NaN;
                    while(isNaN(this.x)){
                      this.x = prompt("Enter the first number:");
                      this.x = parseFloat(this.x);
                    }
                    while(isNaN(this.y)){
                      this.y = prompt("Enter the second number:");
                      this.y = parseFloat(this.y);
                    }
                },
                addition:function()
                {
                    this.getNumbers();   
                    document.write(this.x + "+" + this.y + "=" + (this.x+this.y));
                }
              }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="Calculator.addition()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that `x` and `y` are defined within the `getNumbers()` function's scope. A bad solution would be to declare `x` and `y` in an outer scope, or worst at global scope. A good solution is to return the values of `x` and `y` from the `getNumbers` function and use them afterwards:

```
 function getNumbers() {
     var x = prompt("Enter the first number:");
     var y = prompt("Enter the second number:");
     x = parseInt(x);
     y = parseInt(y);
     return [x, y];
}

function addition(){
    var [x, y] = getNumbers();   
    document.write(x + "+" + y + "=" + (x+y));
}
```

Comment: What is this tuple syntax `var [x,y]` and why don't I know about it? +1

Comment: Array seems like a bad API though -- why not return object where `x` and `y` would have actual names? Relying on tuples will just lead you to http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html. I think that it is a responsibility of the function to provide semantic information about its result, and not a responsibility of the calling code.

Comment: it's called destructuring assignment, and it's quite new in Javascript. It's in the [approved part of the ES6 draft](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-destructuring-assignment.html). It's not a bad API, it gives a way for the function's caller to use whatever name it needs. And it's just modern! :-)

Comment: Thanks @zmo, just saw this too: http://pastebin.com/k8PLLe72 which seems much the same thing.

Comment: @zmo Perl had that too -- and it is bad because the function result becomes meaningless without documentation or looking through source code. The fact that destructuring assignment got into spec does not mean it is the best solution for this particular problem.

Comment: indeed, that's using the object syntax. A cool thing though, on that example is that you can alias an attribute to another name: `var {a: foo} = getTuple(); foo == 'Eddard Stack'` from your example ;-)

Comment: And if we have to use cool new things I would have used http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html -- not sure if anything supports that though. ;)

Comment: @AndreyShchekin python has it and it is not considered as bad. Good documentation is always important, even if you don't return tuples. And it's a far better way to do, than by using globals. Of course you could return an object, but I think it's like trying to kill a fly using a bazooka.

Comment: and why not using the arrow function syntax? :-)

Comment: Btw, is the destructuring syntax widely supported? I am not trying to nitpick, but for a person learning JS unsupported features might be very confusing. It does not work in latest Chrome from what I see.

Comment: hum.. you're right [though their position is quite unclear](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=811) on the subject. Damn.. What are those guys waiting for?